# Checking one column and returning another column, in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Title                Participants
0  ShowA            B. Smith,C. Ball
1  ShowB                   T. Smooth
2  ShowC  K. Dulls,L. Allen,B. Smith
```

I'm splitting on `,` in the Participants column and creating a list for each cell. Next, I check for specific participant(s) in each list. In this example, I'm checking for either `B. Smith` or `K. Dulls`

```
for item in df['Participants']:
    listX = item.split(',')
    if 'B. Smith' in listX or 'K. Dulls' in listX:
        print(listX)
```

This returns:

```
['B. Smith', 'C. Ball']
['K. Dulls', 'L. Allen', 'B. Smith']
```

1) I'm guessing there is a cleaner way to check for multiple participants, in my `if` statement. I'd love any suggestions.

2) This is where i've been spinning in circles, how do I return the `Title` associated with the list(s) I return?

In this example, i'd like to return:

```
ShowA
ShowC
```

---

Setup code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Title': ['ShowA', 'ShowB', 'ShowC'],
                        'Participants': ['B. Smith,C. Ball', 'T. Smooth', 'K. Dulls,L. Allen,B. Smith']})

target_participants = ['B. Smith', 'K. Dulls']
```

Comment: Can you share the DataFrame in a format that is easier to use? See: [mcve].

Comment: Also, depending on the data, there may be a better way of storing it in a tabular format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `get_dummies`

You can use `pandas.Series.str.get_dummies` and create a dataframe where columns are boolean expressions of where names are present.

```
dummies = df.Participants.str.get_dummies(',').astype(bool)
dummies

   B. Smith  C. Ball  K. Dulls  L. Allen  T. Smooth
0      True     True     False     False      False
1     False    False     False     False       True
2      True    False      True      True      False
```

Then we can find your result

```
df.loc[dummies['B. Smith'] | dummies['K. Dulls'], 'Title']

0    ShowA
2    ShowC
Name: Title, dtype: object
```

---

#### `contains`

Otherwise, you can use `pandas.Series.str.contains`.  First we'll need to specify the people you are looking for in a list and then construct a string to use as a regular expression.

```
people_to_look_for = ['B. Smith', 'K. Dulls']
pattern = '|'.join(people_to_look_for)
mask = df.Participants.str.contains(pattern)
df.loc[mask, 'Title']

0    ShowA
2    ShowC
Name: Title, dtype: object
```

Comment: I like the `pandas.Series.str.contains` solution, although it does come with the usual annoyances related to matching words.

Comment: your `contains` solution does exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I am intrigued by the `get_dummies` solution. Would there be an easy way to elaborate on it, in order to list the participants by # of occurrences? (i.e. 'B. Smith' would have 2 occurrences while the rest would have 1).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how great the performance for this would be, although I imagine it's worth the investment if you keep the elements of the `'Participants'` column as lists.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Title': ['ShowA', 'ShowB', 'ShowC'],
                        'Participants': ['B. Smith,C. Ball', 'T. Smooth', 'K. Dulls,L. Allen,B. Smith']})

target_participants = {'B. Smith', 'K. Dulls'}

df['Participants'] = df['Participants'].str.split(',')

print(df, end='\n\n')

contains_parts = ~df['Participants'].map(target_participants.isdisjoint)

print(contains_parts)
```

Output:

```
   Title                    Participants
0  ShowA             [B. Smith, C. Ball]
1  ShowB                     [T. Smooth]
2  ShowC  [K. Dulls, L. Allen, B. Smith]

0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Participants, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you, @AMC! I may be referring back to this, at a later date.